# LazyLoading images into a Gallery

Tags: java, android

If you check out this answer.
[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

Fedor has provided a tutorial on how to lazy load with image view.
But he said it can be used with Gallery with minor modifications.

How do i go about doing this with minor modifications?

Ive Tried this so far.

This is the BaseAdapter
    public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Activity activity;
private String[] data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

    TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
    ImageView image=new ImageView(this.activity);
    text.setText("item "+position);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, image);
    return vi;
}
```

}

And then in my activity i do this..

```
    LazyAdapter adapter=new LazyAdapter(MainMenu.this, myRemoteImages);
 ((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
                      .setAdapter(adapter);
```

It doesnt seem to be working though.

Nothing is showing up

Comment: Check out my edit...I get no debug error either

Comment: [check this library may be it helps you](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/android-universal-image-loader/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I managed to work out. After implementing Fedor's code in a GridView, you must be aware that in the ImageLoader class file there is a class named decodeFile(). In that class Fedor's code automatically resizez the image so that it can become a small thumbnail. You have just to comment the "rescaling" part and your image will appear in full in the GalleryView.